# Get a value of json in android app

Tags: java, android, json

Get a value of json in android app

```
my json result = {"message":"Json","success":1}

Value {"message":"Json","success":1} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

my code :

                HttpEntity ent= resp.getEntity();


                text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(text);
                JSONObject jObj = json.getJSONObject(0);
                Integer sucess= jObj.getInt("success");

                if (sucess == 1){
                    Log.v("JSON" ,"es 1");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are trying to convert a JSONObject to a JSONArray.

Use this

```
HttpEntity ent= resp.getEntity();


            text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);

            int success= -1;
            if(json.has("success"))
                success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1){
                Log.v("JSON" ,"es 1");
            }
```